# How to two or three image in a single link in cakephp?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, cakephp

I want this code in html

```
<a href="images/p191-large.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom: 'zoom11',  smallImage: 'images/p191.jpg' " title="Women's Crepe Printed Black"> 
    <img class="zoom-tiny-image" itemprop="image" src="images/p191.jpg" width="80" height="97" alt=""/>
</a>
```

I have written this code in cakephp to get above result

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("p191.jpg", array(
        "alt" => "Pant Suit",
        "width" => "80",
        "height" => "97",
        'class' => 'zoom-tiny-image'
    )),
    array(
        'controller' => 'admins',
        'action' => '$this->Html->image(p191.jpg)'
    ),
    array(
        'class' => 'cloud-zoom-gallery',
        'title' => 'Women\'s Crepe Printed Black',
        'escape' => false,
        'rel' => "useZoom: 'zoom11', smallImage: 'images/p191.jpg' "
    )
);
?>
```

but getting this as output

```
<a href="/stylishtailor1/admins/ ;image(p191.jpg)" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" title="Women's Crepe Printed Black" rel="useZoom: 'zoom11', smallImage: 'images/p191.jpg' ">
    <img src="/stylishtailor1/images/p191.jpg" alt="Pant Suit" width="80" height="97" class="zoom-tiny-image" />
</a>
```

how can I do this, please reply on this???

Comment: Your question is a mess. Please consider rewriting.

Comment: Please use the code-button when creating a post to nicely indent and highlight code. What is your current output? (put it in 'code')

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest code to your desired one:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link(
            $this->Html->image('/images/p191-large.jpg', array('alt' => 'Pant Suit', 'width' => '80', 'height' => '97', 'class' => 'zoom-tiny-image')),
            'images/p191-large.jpg',
            array('class' => 'cloud-zoom-gallery', 'title' => 'Women\'s Crepe Printed Black', 'escape' => false, 'rel' => "useZoom: 'zoom11', smallImage: 'images/p191.jpg' ")
    );
?>
```

To make sure it working properly, you have to check two things. Path of image (first argument of `image()` function) should have full path if it's not located under webroot/img or if it's there, starting `/` could be ommited.

The second thing to check is your url location (second argument in `link()` function). You can pass it as string or as routing array as well. In your example you pass really weird array.

Comment: hi friend thanks for your reply, but i am still not getting the desired result, i am getting now(<a href="/stylishtailor1/admins/images/p191-large.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" 
title="Women's Crepe Printed Black" rel="useZoom: 'zoom11', smallImage: 'images/p191.jpg' ">
<img src="/stylishtailor1/images/p191-large.jpg" alt="Pant Suit" width="80" height="97" 
class="zoom-tiny-image" /></a>)